# Input element width inside of a table cell

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to make the following working the way I want it to. I want to have an Input element changing its width to the provided cell's width. Here is code:

```
<table style="margin-top:10px;width:80.5%;font-size:14px">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:5%">
            <span translate>CaseNumber</span>:
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:5%">
            <span>
                <input easyui-textboxreadonly readonly ng-model="caseid" style="width:80px;height:32px;background-color:#72A4D2"/>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:2%">
            <span translate>Title</span>:
        </td>
        <td style="width:88%">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <input easyui-textbox data-options="required:true" ng-model="title" style="height:32px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the input in the last cell to take all the width of  the cell it's in.
Unless I provide a width of the input it's not happening.

Comment: so if you set its width to 100% it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `width: 100%` on the `input` element itself, not on a `div` surrounding it (you can get rid of that `div` altogether in fact).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1qda1jpx/2/

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-top:10px;width:80.5%;font-size:14px">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:5%">
            <span translate>CaseNumber</span>:
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:5%">
            <span>
                <input easyui-textboxreadonly readonly ng-model="caseid" style="width:80px;height:32px;background-color:#72A4D2"/>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:2%">
            <span translate>Title</span>:
        </td>
        <td style="width:88%">
            <input easyui-textbox data-options="required:true" ng-model="title" style="height:32px;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set width: 100% for that input element. Otherwise it wont happen.